# How do you rename a list to a variable in Python

Tags: python, list, rename

I'm trying to create a random string of numbers saved to a list, then rename the list further in the code. I've tried using dictionaries to store the names but that didn't work, I've also tried simply `newListName=oldListName` which when I attempted to print **newListName** it returns a **NameError**

Comment: Can you include the code?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do, and saying "I tried using dictionaries but that didn't work" is not an adequate problem description. Almost certainly you want to use a dictionary. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the list into a new one as:

> newListName=oldListName[:]

This would not give you the NameError!
Make sure that oldListName is defined as list before and then copied into another list.